# How to get dag start and end time and dag run duration in airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to get the dag start time and end time to calculate the duration/elapsed time and show it in airflow UI.

I tried with python date time but looks like airflow already records these things. I want to know if there is any way to leverage that.

I don't want to get the details from the database because it will complicate things. I want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the start time of the DAG by using a template reference (for example `ts`): https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

To access template references you can, among others, use a PythonOperator:

```
def python_method(ds, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['ts'])

op1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_ts',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=python_method,
    dag=dag)
```

Retrieving the end time of a DAG that is still running is not possible using this method as it is still in progress when you access this information.